# Разбиения на отдельные строки и ввод в sql

Tags: php, html, sql, массивы, база-данных

нужно чтоб введенные дание в форме разделение энтером вводились в sql базу построчно. Написал следующий скрипт но он только разбивает на отдельные строки, а в sql не переносит. Можете помочь?
Код формы:

```
 <div class="container mt-4">
 <form action="exe.php" method="post">
  <p><b>Input:</b></p>
  <p><textarea type="text" name="input" id="input"></textarea></p>
  <p><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">INPUT</button></p>
 </form>
```

Код исполнения:

```
    <?php
$input = filter_var(trim($_POST['input']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'a_db');
$lines = explode("\r\n", $input);
foreach ($lines as $key=>$val)
 {
    echo $val. "<br/>";
 }
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `cc` (`aaa`)
    VALUES ('$lines')");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_close($mysql);
?>
```

Comment: "разделение энтером вводились в sql базу построчно" - это что? это как? расшифруйте...

Comment: ну так и чего там у вас? `Array`в базе получили, вместо того того что ожидали?.
Если есть массив строк, который надо в базу внести, то надо либо по каждому элементу запрос вполнять, либо инсерт запрос написать в виде, позволяющем вносить сразу несколько строк. Но уж никак не пихать массив в строку.

Comment: как создать такой запрос "инсерт запрос записать в виде, позволяющем вносить сразу несколько строк"?

Comment: в одной форме: 
25
58
456
.....
и так далее